# ASP.Net Core MVC - Calling a different view from a controller

Tags: asp.net-core, model-view-controller, view, controller

I am new to ASP.Net Core MVC and have a question. I have a home controller which uses a index view to show a list of customers in a table. Against each row I have two buttons; an edit and delete button. When the user clicks on the edit button it calls an action in my home controller called editcustomer passing in the customer Id. In this action I create a view model and populate all the models with the correct data. I then need to call my customer details view with this view model to display all the customer information.
I am not sure how I switch from my home controller to my customer details controller and display my customer details view.

I am new to this and I am going through a ton of YouTube videos to study but I just need a bit of guidance on how to do this process correctly.

Below is the code for my EditCustomer action but it errors because it's looking for the view in the home (controller name) folder and not the CustomerDetails folder under the view folder:

```
        public IActionResult EditCustomer(int customer_Id)
        {
            CustomerDetailsViewModel customerDetails = new CustomerDetailsViewModel();
            customerDetails.customer = customerRepository.getCustomer(customer_Id);
            customerDetails.titles = customerRepository.getTitles();
            customerDetails.ePCs = customerRepository.getEPCs();
            customerDetails.jobStages = customerRepository.getJobStages();
            customerDetails.propertyStatus = customerRepository.getPropertyStatus();
            customerDetails.propertyTypes = customerRepository.getPropertyTypes();
            customerDetails.heatSources = customerRepository.getHeatSources();
            customerDetails.fuelTypes = customerRepository.getFuelTypes();
            customerDetails.ePCRequesters = customerRepository.getEPCRequesters();
            customerDetails.ePCCompanies = customerRepository.getEPCCompanies();
            customerDetails.surveyors = customerRepository.getSurveyors();
            customerDetails.surveyStatus = customerRepository.getSurveyStatus();
            customerDetails.installationInstallers = customerRepository.getInstallationInstallers();
            customerDetails.loftInstallers = customerRepository.getLoftInstallers();
            customerDetails.heatInstallers = customerRepository.getHeatInstallers();

            return View("CustomerDetails",customerDetails);
        }
```

Comment: `return View` only search under the current controller folder of  `Views`  or the `Shared` folder

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `RedirectToAction`,pass model to a action in another controller,and return View with the model.Here is a demo:

BController:

```
public class BController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult TestRedirect()
        {
            return RedirectToAction("CustomerDetails", "Home", new CustomerDetailsViewModel { titles="titlesample"});
            
        }
    }
```

HomeController:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        
        public IActionResult CustomerDetails(CustomerDetailsViewModel c)
        {
            return View(c);
        }  
    }
```

View(Home/CustomerDetails)：

```
@model CustomerDetailsViewModel
<h1>
    @Model.titles
</h1>
```

result:
[image]